# Headings retrieval in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this Firebase database:
[image: Firebase structure]

What android code do I write to get just all the headings,
(uRpg0XxX...., wleC7AJBug....) and so in an array list or any other data structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

If you want to get a specific data using a phone number then you can use a Query like this

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("profiles");

Query phoneQuery = ref.orderByChild(phoneNo).equalTo("+923336091371");
phoneQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

I think this is the best method.